# firebase cloud function get document inside callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

with firebase cloud functions, if I want to reference a document ('/users/' + userId) inside a callback, is this how I would do it?  the userId is inside the first snapshot, so I would need to call another async call to get the user document, but I think something is wrong with my syntax since this gives an error.

```
exports.onCommentCreation = functions.firestore.document('/forum/threads/threads/{threadId}/comments/{commentId}')
 .onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {

     var commentDataSnap = snapshot; 
     var userId = commentDataSnap.data().userId; 
     var userRef = await functions.firestore.document('/users/' + userId).get();
     var userEmail = userRef.data().email; 
});
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide your debugging information here.  We can't see how you are triggering this function, the data in your documents and variables, and the contents of your logs.  There needs to be enough information here that anyone can use to reproduce the problem as you see it.

Comment: "since this gives an error" Please edit your question to show the exact error message and stack trace you get.

Comment: ah thanks, the answer worked out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line `var userRef = await functions.firestore.document('/users/' + userId).get();` change `functions.firestore.document` to `admin.firestore().doc`.

Something like this:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.onCommentCreation = functions.firestore
  .document('/forum/threads/threads/{threadId}/comments/{commentId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {

    // use const because the values are not changing
    const userId = snapshot.data().userId;
    const userRef = await db.doc('/users/' + userId).get(); // <-- this line
    const userEmail = userRef.data().email;
  });
```